# Using average to find probability of events

Tags: probability

Let's say we have two darts players. One misses an average of 2 darts per game, and one misses an average of 5 darts per game. What is the probability of each player missing no darts? If these events are independent, what is the probability they both miss no darts?

How would we solve this problem? I'm really confused how we're supposed to be able to go from an average to a probability. Do we have to use the bell curve and standard deviations or something similar?

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

A reliable average rate, or *frequency*, is an reasonable estimation for probability.

You know player $A$ misses 2 darts per game.   Divide by the number of darts thrown during a game and you have the *miss rate*, the probability that a particular dart will miss.

Likewise for player $B$ missing 5 darts per game.

Of course, the piece of information you are missing is: how many darts are *thrown* per game.  You won't get very far without that.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many random variables with a given average, so indeed the problem cannot be solved as it is. To compute a probability, you need to agree on the distribution followed by the random variables "number of darts missed" by each player.

For instance, if there are $5$ darts in one game, you could imagine that each dart has a probability of $2/5$ of being a miss, and agree on a binomial distribution. But you don't even know the total number of darts per game. This is really a strange problem.